# positioning issue (css popup overlap)

Tags: css, css-float

I have a problem with css popup. I am hidden some content in span tags and show it when I hover over a text. But there is a overlap and the text in the second line is overlapping the popup. And the border for the popup is messed up. The content is on  [this link](http://delivery3.water-7.com/index.php/restaurants/manufacturers/3/Barcelona-Restaurant-&-Winebar/products). And I am using following css:

```
 .rest-cat 
 {  
clear: both;
padding: 3px 40px 0 0!important;
width: 600px;
 }
.rest-menuitem 
{
position: static;

float: left;
width: 254px;
padding: 3px 5px 0 0!important;
border-top: 1px dotted #DDD;
}

.dishname{
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
float: left;
width: 229px;
 }

.dishprice{
position: relative;
float: right;
width: 25px;
 }



.product
{
    width: 600px;
padding: 0px 0px 20px 20px!important;

} 

.dishname span
{
display: none;
text-decoration: none;
}

.dishname:hover 
{
overflow: hidden;
text-decoration: none;
}

.dishname:hover span
{
display: block;
position: static;
top: 0px;
left: 170px;
width: 320px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
color: #335500;
font-weight: normal;
background: #e5e5e5;
text-align: left;
border: 1px solid #666;
z-index: 200;
}
```

Is there a easy fix for this? I already tried using       position: relative; and added z-index to all the CSS tags. They didn't work and I am stuck on it for a day.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want it to be doing?

Comment: for such a simple layout, I've never seen so many `<div>`'s in my entire life. lol Might want to straighten that up a little.

Comment: most of the div's are generated by redshop and joomla templates. The one I am working on is popup when you hover over the names in the menu

Comment: How do I push this post to get more answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your popups are being clipped is because of this CSS:

```
.dishname:hover {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Removing that would be a good place to start.

Next, `z-index` only affects elements with a `position` property other than `static`. Use `relative` and they will render the same but the z-index will have an effect.

After that there are a lot of different things that could be affecting the layering I would start like @Michael Rader said by cleaning up your HTML, you have a lot of unnecessary wrappers.

Comment: overflow fixed the border problem. And for the overlaps I tried position: relative it didnt help. And the page is dynamically generated by Joomla and redshop. I can add div's but I cannot remove them (or more like I am not sure how to modify Joomla stuff).

Comment: You're right, I can't seem to get the overlaps to work even with `position: relative`. This may be some quirk related to Joomla that I don't know about (not a Joomla dev). Hopefully someone more familiar with the CMS will have seen this before.